# how to remove the color formed on the edge of satellite image?

Tags: raster, erdas-imagine, image-mosaic

my AOI requires two scene of satellite image but when I try to mosaic the images using ERDAS imagine, the color of the edge is seen forming black line after mosaic! so please how can I remove the image edge color?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the outside edge of the combined image, or along the join?

Perhaps the `Near Black` tool in QGIS would help. `Raster->Analysis->Near black`.

Or if the colour is not present anywhere else, you can `Reclassify` that pixel type to NoData or whatever class you want.

Comment: The near black tool is really a GDAL tool, called "nearblack": See http://www.gdal.org/nearblack.html

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to draw a border shape around your AOI, save it to a shapefile and the use GDAL's crop_to_cutline command to crop the image to those borders.
After performing this operation on both of your sat. images, you should be fine to mosaic them!

Hope it helped!

Comment: Was this method useful for you? Please let me know!